# ValueError: no json object could be decoded (Head First Python-chapter 8)

Tags: python, json, sl4a

I'm new to python and I'm learning using Head First Python. I've gotten to chapter 8 and I'm stuck with the error message above. After writing the coachapp.py script given by the book and uploading it onto android emulator device, I'm stuck with this error message. I have been at it for weeks now. The error comes from this line of code:

athlete = json.loads(send_to_server(web_server + get_data_cgi, {'which_athlete': which_athlete}))

...although my web server-log indicates that the data has been sent successfully:

b'{"Name": "James Lee", "DOB": "2002-3-14", "Top3": ["2.01", "2.16", "2.22"]}\r\n'

Comment: The `send_to_server` works then and sends a request to your server. What the server returns is not a json loadable string I bet. What would you get if you print the result of `send_to_server`? like `response = send_to_serve(...)` and then `print(response)`

Comment: just wanted to give the same advice, that @plumsempy wrote.

If you have problems it's always a good idea to split long lines into separate lines and print or log the intermediate results.

It is very likely, that the return value of send_to_server is not what you expect it to be.